# Not understanding drawAt() method for com.google.android.maps.Overlay

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay

Trying to make an google maps overlay in an android program. Inside of my overlay's draw method, I have two ways of adding a pin. One of them works, and one does not. Unfortunately, the one that does not work is also the only one that has the ability to add a shadow! Any help?

```
@Override
public void draw(android.graphics.Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
        boolean shadow) {

    Point po = mapView.getProjection().toPixels(mapView.getMapCenter(),
            null);

    // This does _not_ work, but I would really like it to!
    drawAt(canvas, mapView.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.map_marker_v),
           po.x, po.y, false);

    // This does work, but only does half the job
    canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mapView.getResources(),
            R.drawable.map_marker_v), po.x, po.y, null);


}
```

Edit: fixed type

Comment: Can you explain exactly what 'does not work' translate into? Are you receiving any error messages in a logcat window? Does your app crash? Does it not draw, etc?

Comment: Anthony, sure! It simply does not draw. No error messages of any kind in logcat, but app does not crash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem may simply be that you haven't set the bounds on the drawable in `drawAt()`.  You can either manually set the bounds using [`Drawable.setBounds()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setBounds(android.graphics.Rect)), or you can use ItemizedOverlay's convenience methods [`boundCenter()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#boundCenter(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) or [`boundCenterBottom()`](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#boundCenterBottom(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)).

I believe the reason the second method works is because with a decoded Bitmap you don't have to specify the bounds of the Drawable.

Answer (score 1):

At first sight, nothing stands out to me as to what could be causing your pin to not draw. But, I might have found a temporarily solution.

Looking on google lead me to [this post](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/2d96bf4ddd5a091a/a1e01031d90ca1ff?lnk=raot) where an user posts their version of an Overlay with the ability to add an icon along with a shadow. It might be what your looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! I had actually thought about doing this too ha ha